# startime to be set in calendar

Tags: java, calendar

I want jan 1st 2012 as long value from calendar object as a start time how to get this,i am doing as below

```
   Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        today.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        today.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        long startTime = today.getTime().getTime();
```

Comment: Any reason why you're not also setting the year, month and day?

Comment: no reason,i want the start time as long value ,it should be for jan1st 2012

Comment: But my point is that nowhere in that code have you expressed "January 1st 2012" - why not? If you do so, does that not do what you want?

Comment: i am not knowing how to set it

Comment: Well you've apparently worked out how to set the MILLISECOND, SECOND, MINUTE and HOUR. Try looking at the documentation for Calendar (and applying a bit of reasoning) for you might set the MONTH, YEAR, and DAY_OF_MONTH...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Calendar firstOfYear = Calendar.getInstance();
firstOfYear.clear();
firstOfYear.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);
firstOfYear.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1); //first day of the year.
```

Comment: this sets the value as jan 1 2012? i canoot fine day of year param in calendar

Comment: @harqs: "I am getting error" is *never* a good description on its own. You should *always* say what that error is. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @harqs what version/type of java are you using? in the documentation of `Calendar` you can see DAY_OF_YEAR is a valid, static value.

Comment: i am using in this way now   today.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
   today.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
   today.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);

Answer (score 1):

```
this is the another way

String str_date="01-JAN-2012";
DateFormat formatter ; 
Date date ; 
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date); 
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
System.out.println("=======>"+cal.getTimeInMillis());
```